# PHP GET function not getting data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php GET function

```
function genre_get($genre) {

$this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT games.id, games.title, games.developer, reviews.NoReviews ';
    $sql .= 'FROM games INNER JOIN ';
$sql .= '(SELECT ean, COUNT(*) as NoReviews ';
$sql .= 'FROM reviews GROUP BY ean) reviews ';
$sql .= 'ON games.ean = reviews.ean ';
$sql .= 'WHERE games.genre= "'.$genre.'";';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
$info->games=$data;
$this->response($data, 200);
 }
```

And although there are no errors its not outputting any JSON data. Using the sql syntax in the mysql command prompt it does generate a table however using this on the apigee console returns nothing.

```
 function genre_get($genre) {
     $this->load->database();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM games ';
        $sql .= 'WHERE genre = "'.$genre.'";';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();
    $info->games=$data;
        $this->response($data, 200);
     }
```

I used this function previously and it worked and got the data required

Comment: What framework/library are you using?

Comment: Seems like you have no related rows in the `reviews` table

Comment: code igniter and the same sql works using mysql and it does load related rows

Answer (score -1):

```
$info->games=$data;
```

`$info` looks undefined, if that's your complete function.

Comment: im using code igniter and that didnt need to be defined in the one function i have working

Comment: @user3187726 but i don't see it getting passed into the function by any means.

Comment: @plutov What's not a question?

Comment: im not sure that infos the issue because that line worked when using the 2nd php function which does a similar thing except that the first one counts the amount of reviews